# Angularjs : Select combination from a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple list :

```
$scope.myArr = ["a_b_c","a_b_d","a_e_g","f_t_r","f_t_g","f_u_m"];
```

From this I want to build 3 `<select></select>`.

The first one will contain the first items of the array separated by `_`.
So `["a","a","a","f","f","f"]`

The second `["b","b","e","t","t","u"]`

The third `["c","d","g","r","g","m"]`

I've built these 3 arrays and I've make unique values.

What I need is that for example if I select `a` in the first select, the second one will only show `b,b,e`.

I actually want to respect the possible combinations from the array of start (`$scope.myArr)`

Any ideas on how can I achieve it ?

http://jsfiddle.net/uxo0jue3/

Comment: Do you have any issues with preprocessing it?

Comment: Not sure what it means :/

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/v0gLkkqn/) works, but you can't use distinct, so its probably not the solution you are looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop your array, split the values, and create a leveled object. The simply link it to the view:

```
var myArr = ["a_b_c","a_b_d","a_e_g","f_t_r","f_t_g","f_u_m"];
var levels = {};

myArr.forEach(function(arr) {
    var split = arr.split("_");
    if (!levels[split[0]])
        levels[split[0]] = {};

    if (!levels[split[0]][split[1]])
        levels[split[0]][split[1]] = []

    if (levels[split[0]][split[1]].indexOf(split[2]) === -1) 
        levels[split[0]][split[1]].push(split[2])
})

$scope.levels = levels;
```

And the view:

```
<div ng-controller="myAppList">
    <select name="clienT" ng-model="clientW" ng-options="letter as letter for (letter, opts) in levels"></select>
    <select name="projecT" ng-model="clientX" ng-options="letter as letter for (letter, opts) in levels[clientW]"></select>
    <select name="platforM" ng-model="clientZ" ng-options="letter as letter for letter in levels[clientW][clientX]"></select>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uxo0jue3/4/

Comment: Could you just explain me things inside each `ng-options` please ?

Comment: @BipBip -- Sure. So, the first 2 syntaxes use the object repeat syntax `(key, value) in obj` - and once an option is selected - the next `select` simply uses the next level in the object to display the options. If `a` is selected from the first - the options for the next `select` are generated from `$scope.levels['a']` - and so on and so forth.

Comment: It's a bit confusing - just notice that every `select` is based on the previous `select` `ngModel`

Comment: I will probably need some time to figure this out. I'll give the bounty asap anyway, awesome answer , thanks

Comment: No problem - leave a comment if you have more questions!